# C++/Cx - Need access to variable within the Main Page of the Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-metro, c++-cx

I am creating a W8 app in C++/CX. I have MainPage.xaml files with WebView object, and Dispatcher object. I have created a separate class to decouple the code. However I need to communicate back to some of the objects in MainPage. I tried inheriting the objects like this:

```
Downloader::Downloader(CoreDispatcher dispatcher1, WebView webView1) {
    webView = webView1;
    dispatcher = dispatcher1;
}
```

Although C++ does not like the syntax above.

I guess another approach would be if I could use App.xaml.h / App.xaml.cpp as a singleton to call it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using an Event and delegate to communicate back in native code,
or can run InvokeScript on WebView to invoke javascript from native code.